# Name for a T-shaped piece of hardware with a screw hole in a "shaft"

Tags: mounting

What is the name of a hardware piece like on the drawing, with a thread in the hole?

[image: drawing]

I need it to mount a guide wheel for a sliding door, like on the picture below:

[image: picture]

UPD: replaced the picture with a drawing.

Comment: A T nut comes to mind but if it matches the image you refer to the that is clearly labelled already.

Comment: Google "blind shelf support". Some of those have threaded holes in the end that meets the plate.

Comment: Based on the language used I believe the OP means the shaft has a hole in it that is threaded not that the shaft is threaded. I formulated my answer based on that assumption.

Comment: Thank you, now I realized the picture was misleading because it was only superficially similar to what I need. Updated the post with drawing and new pic.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the hint, I found "slab-base nut", which seems to be the thing I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is "Slab-based T-nut" or "Slab-based nut".

Thanks to @SolarMike for pointing out in the right direction (T-nut).

Answer (score 2):

There is no common name for what you describe; it is not a standard type of hardware.

Product and equipment manufacturers custom make all types of unique and specific parts, not all of them have common names. That's why the supplier in your link used a self-describing name ("T Shaped Shelf Support Holder Bracket") instead of some common term.

Comment: I have updated the question with the drawing, maybe this one is standard?

Answer (score 0):

If the mounting hole is in the shaft, is the "T" necessary? Closest I could find is pictured below.

[image]

Comment: Updated with the drawing - I need a hole on the other side of the shaft.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware in the photo you posted are floating shelf brackets or floating shelf hardware. I have never seen nor can I find any that have threaded hole in the shaft. Sometimes the shelf that slips over the shaft has a hole in the bottom with a Allen key set screw that tightens up against the shaft To keep the shelf from sliding off of the bracket. Some also have a leveling adjustment component built in.

If you need one with a threaded hole then your best bet is to take those two a machine shop and have a hole drilled and tapped with threads.

Another option would be to buy some and drill your holes and get a tap and die set and thread them yourself. To do it yourself you will need a drill press or a drill and a vice, metal drilling drill bits and lubrication oil, A set punch, and a tap and die tool set.

EDIT: based on the updated information in the question I found [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D98711V)

If this is not exactly what you’re looking for then use the term **

> sliding door roller guide

** to search the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. This was the picture I found, not the part I really needed - updated with the drawing. I need a bracket like this one to mount a small wheel horizontally to guide a sliding door.

Comment: @dottedmag. I updated my answer with a link to a product on Amazon that may be what you’re looking for.